# ¿cargar un componente de forma dinámica? angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy intentando cargar mi componente "level" de forma dinámica. 
Tengo unos archivos nombrados de la siguiente manera: Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4... etc.
Estoy buscando una forma de cargar los componentes.

Intentando esto:

```
<app-level{{userInfo.level}}></app-level{{userInfo.level}}>
```

Pero esto no funciona! ¿Alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Este es mi level.component.ts:

```
 export class LevelComponent implements OnInit {
  userInfo: any = {
    level: '',
    id: ''
  }

  responceText: any = {
    message:''
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private ConnServices: ConnectionService,
    private userFunctions:UserFunctions) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('log') !== 'true') {
      this.router.navigate(['/'])
    }
    this.userInfo.id = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
    //this.userInfo.level = userFunctions.getActualLevel(this.userInfo.id);
    console.log(userFunctions.getActualLevel(this.userInfo.id));

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  nextLevel() {
    let levelNum = parseInt(this.userInfo.level);
    let levelChange = String(levelNum + 1);
    console.log(levelChange);
    this.ConnServices.updateLevel(this.userInfo.id, levelChange).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.responceText = data;
      console.log(this.responceText[0].message);

    })
  }

  lLogOut() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }
```

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera (level.component.html):

```
<div *ngIf="userInfo.level == '1'">
    <app-level1></app-level1>
</div>
<div *ngIf="userInfo.level == '2'">
    <app-level2></app-level2>
</div>
```

Me gustaría hacerlo de una forma mas simple.

Comment: Hola. No funciona así. Pero puedes usar el `RouterOutlet` para cambiar de nivel`

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir cómo es tu componente Level?

Comment: @OscarDavidDiazFortaleché. Tengo variaos componentes llamados: Level1, Level2... Y un componente principal que es el que se encarga de llamar el Level.. correspondiente.

Comment: @OscarDavidDiazFortaleché Añadí mi componente Level a la pregunta.

Comment: @Angel Muchas gracias lo intentare.

Comment: Es que no entiendo por qué hiciste un componente por cada nivel, con un solo componente level podrías detectar de que nivel es recibiendo un parámetro y de acuerdo al nivel muestras u ocultas algo.

Comment: Es que soy nuevo en esto. Pero ya lo solucione. Como mi leves son solo texto, los estoy almacenando en la base de datos y luego las cargo en mi app. por ejemplo: SELECT * FROM `leves` WHERE level = 1... luego la muestro en mi web: {{level.title}} {{level.question}}

Comment: Que bueno que pudiste resolverlo.